# Converting a float to a string problem in C#

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I am currently using Unity3d and I am making a score.

I made my score based off of my player's Z-axis.

My player is at -29 on the Z-axis and I don't want my score to start on a negative number, I want it to start a zero.

May someone please explain how I can add 29 to my **scoreText.text**.

I have only just started C# a few days ago.

Thank you in advance.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player; 
    public Text scoreText;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      int abs = 29;
      scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0"); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public Transform player; 
public Text scoreText;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
  int abs = 29;
  int z = player.position.z;
  scoreText.text = (abs + z).ToString("0"); 

}
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying:   Score.cs(13,17): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). This is after I did what you said. I follow what you are saying except I don't understand the error

Comment: Probably means your `player.position.z` is of type `float` so you need to change `int z` to `float z` in sjk answer.

Comment: Thank you very much sjk and @Portland Runner. I learned something new and was able to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution should work for all negative numbers, not just -29 (you don't want it to break if someone has a score of -30, or -58, etc.).  A general purpose solution to this problem could work like this:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform player; 
    public Text scoreText;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = Math.Max(0, player.position.z).ToString("0");
    }
}
```

Note that 'Math.Max' has overloads for all primitive types of numbers, such as int, uint, double, float, etc.  Fortunately for us, the compiler is smart enough to recognize that ints can be converted to floats without data loss, but not the other way around, so it will treat the 0 as a float, call the appropriate Math.Max method, and build successfully.